# Create xml with attributes in scala

Tags: xml, scala, xml-attribute

How i can set attribute value like value for elements in scala.xml

This not work :(

```
def getXml(fooValue: String, barValue: String): Node = 
    val fooBar = <foo bar="{barValue}">
       { fooValue }
    </foo>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it without quotes: `<foo bar={barValue}>`

Answer (score 0):

This way it would work:

## defintion:

```
def createXMLElement(value: String, attributeValue: String) : Node =   
<foo attribute={attributeValue}>{value}</foo>
```

## Example

```
scala> createXMLElement("Hello World", "boring")
res2: scala.xml.Node = <foo attribute="boring">Hello World</foo>
```

In the example given you `assign` the result to a `val` and expect the return type `Node`. The returntype of the assignement is `Unit` though.